# Lightweight image viewer with real-time editing features

Tags: image-viewer, image-editing, png, jpg

I most often read books from scans rather than paper, I also highly preferred it to be in the form of batch of jpgs/pngs rather than in a single pdf since it can give me a very fast overview of the whole book. It will also allow me to quickly open multiple separate pages at once to quickly compare.

The problem is when I want to quickly underline something. This isn't a thing that the Windows Image Viewer can do. So can anyone here recommend a good lightweight image viewer with simple editing features, at least some kind of simple pen tool? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I assume you also want forward/backward navigation? Few editors have that so it's important to mention

Comment: Yes, a forward/backward navigation is very important.

Answer (score 1):

I can happily recommend two programs to do this:

1. [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) will allow you to quickly page back and forth between your scans. As long as you also install the Paint plugin, you can press F12 to perform quick edits such as adding underlines.
2. [XnView](http://www.xnview.com/) will also allow you to quickly page back and forth between pages of your scans.  The Paint option (located under the **Filter** menu)  will allow you to perform quick edits such as adding underlines.

Both are freeware (gratis) and are excellent.  Donations are accepted by the authors.  You can't go wrong with either... or both!

They are also both available as portable applications on [PortableApps.com](http://portableapps.com/).

Enjoy!